# How to switch databases in AWS Athena using JDBC driver?

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to execute a sql statement against Athena using sqlworkbench.  What would be the solution to switching a databases in Athena, or more generally Athena through the jdbc?

```
use AwsDataCatalog.geoosm
```

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: use
> AwsDataCatalog.geoosm [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been
> thrown from the AWS Athena client. line 1:19: mismatched input '.'
> expecting  [Execution ID not available] [SQL State=HY000, DB
> Errorcode=100071] 1 statement failed.
>
> Execution time: 0.18s

My SQL syntax in [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html) comes from [Presto documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/sql/use.html) which from my understanding is the syntax used by Athena.

> 8.39. USE Synopsis
>
> USE catalog.schema USE schema

Comment: When you say that you want to switch databases are you trying to query the table from different database? and if yes have you tried querying  different_db.tablename?

Answer (score 2):

The use statement which is supported in presto is not supported in Athena at this time.

But for cross database queries lower-case **awsdatacatalog.geoosm**, actually works.